# search for series of numbers and group them in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Here i have a long list of numbers that scene changes of a video.

Sometimes because of close up actions there are a series of number like this

```
19068:19069
19069:19070
19070:19071
19071:19072
19072:19073
19073:19074
19074:19075
19075:19076
```

and i want a way to search through the list and group the above example into

19068:19076

Any ideas?

cheers

Comment: A regular expression is the only way to do complex manipulations in text in Notepad++, and what you want is not doable in a regex. It doesn't have a way to do math to find out if the numbers are sequential or not, so it wouldn't be able to recognize gaps.

Comment: That's a pity. Is there any other software/ways of doing it?

Comment: You can't ask for software recommendations here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. There's no way to do what you're asking in NP++. You'll have to find another way to do it. It's impossible to give you suggestions, because I know nothing about your programming or other skills or knowledge. Your question here is about NP++ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to delete numbers when they are equal  at the end of a line and the beginning of next line.

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:(\d+)\n\1`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:           # colon
(\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digit
\n          # line feed, you can use \r\n for windows EOL or \R for any kind of linebreak
\1          # backreference to group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @user10246830: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)